# React.js start a new line after every number

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am fetching a tracklist from my database which has this format :

"
*01. Intro
02. Waage
03. Hyänen (feat. Samra)
04. Ich will es bar (feat. Haftbefehl)
05. Am Boden bleiben (feat. Casper & Montez)*
"

It is one single String. Right now I am simply calling it with :

```
if (album && album.title) {
    trackList = (
        <div className={'trackList'} style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>
            {album.tracklist}
        </div>
    );
}
```

and {trackList} in my App. My goal is to style it, so it makes a new line when a **new** Number starts. Is there an way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your string to an array by `split` method and then iterating over array by `map` method, like this:

```
if (album && album.tracklist) {
    trackList = (
        <div className={'trackList'} style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>
            {album.tracklist
                .trim()
                .split(/\D(?=\d+\.\s)/g)
                .map((t, i) => (
                    <p key={i}>{t}</p>
                ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

instead of `<p>` tag in the above code, you can use any html tag, to generate your expected result.